# When Paypal Standard pay as Guest (no paypal account) Session Expired message on Thank You

Tags: paypal

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7 with paypal standard.  When someone proceeds to paypal and chooses the guest option (no account) to pay with credit card, it processes normally.  Yet, when returning to the CiviCRM they get the contribution page form again (not the 'thank you page') and a message that 'session expired'.  This behavior is consistent across these browsers: Chrome, Edge.

Anyone seen this?  Is there a setting or change within CiviCRM to prevent this?  People are confused and making a second donation.

[image: guest button is down at the bottom]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the existing Paypal account had its Primary Email set to one that was different from the Merchant Email used for Paypal login. Making these both the same fixed the pending contribution issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have a new site which went live yesterday and we are also getting the same behaviour. Also in CiviCRM all the Contributions are still pending.

Olly

Comment: Olly, are you on 4.7.12?  I'm not seeing "pending" on all contributions.  Most are completed.  Have you checked 1) the correct email in paypal.com 2) the 'auto return' as well the 3) IPN

Comment: This has been files in JIRA as a bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19602